# java how to draw a G-clef and F-clef using points or curves

Tags: java, music-notation

I am making a music app using Graphics 2D, and I have managed to draw the stave and the music notes. I am now trying to draw a G-clef

[image: Image of G-clef]

and an F-clef

[image: Image of F-clef]

If there is another possible way to do it, I will appreciate.

NB: I have looked around for two days and I have seen questions that are similar but I haven't yet seen a solution.

Comment: Have you considered just finding clip-art of the clefs and using that directly?

Comment: Thanks for that idea, please tell me how to do that. I will really appreciate.

Comment: Did you try to print the strings "\uD834\uDD1E" and "\uD834\uDD22" ? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d122/index.htm

Comment: Ah, @David 's suggestion is even better.

Comment: It draws a small square. am I missing some fonts in my system?

Comment: I downloaded "bravura" fonts and it worked. Thanks a lot. can I post it as an answer? http://www.smufl.org/fonts/

Comment: Post & accept - I even upvoted it.

Comment: Thanks @JoopEggen . I did that, though they'll allow me to accept it as an answer two days from now. I will do that.

Comment: Glad it worked :) Yes, post it and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using points and curves is not the best way. Thanks to @David, I found out that unicodes work best. To use a unicode in printing a string,

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class UnicodeText {
public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame f = new JFrame() {
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    Font font = new Font("Bravura", Font.PLAIN, 32);

    g2.setFont(font);
    g2.drawString("\uD834\uDD1E", 40, 80);// Gclef
    g2.drawString("\uD834\uDD22", 40, 80);// Fclef
  }
};
f.setSize(200,200);
f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Download the "bravura" font [here](http://www.smufl.org/fonts/) and find the unicode standard chart [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf)

Hope it helps someone.